# Field of struct as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have a code in MSVC 2008:

```
template< class T, class FieldType, FieldType T::*FieldPtr >
struct EqualBy {
    EqualBy( const FieldType & value ) : m_filedValue( value ) {}
    bool operator()( const T & r ) const {
        return m_filedValue == r.*FieldPtr;
    }
private:
    const FieldType m_filedValue;
};

...

struct S {
    int field1;
    ...
};
typedef EqualBy< S, int, &S::field1 > EqualByField1;

...

typedef std::vector< S > SVect;
SVect v;
SVect::const_iterator found = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), EqualByField1( 42 ) );
```

it works fine. But now I want to move the EqualByField1 typedef into the struct S. like this

```
struct S {
    int field1;
...

    typedef EqualBy< S, int, &S::field1 > EqualByField1;
};
```

to decrease the scope of this typedef and to "beautify" the caller code like this

```
SVect::const_iterator found = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), S::EqualByField1( 42 ) );
```

but I got following errors

> error C2327: 'S::field1' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
>   error C2065: 'field1' : undeclared identifier

The question is: Is there any solution of this problem, except of to derive from S like that

```
struct SS : public S {
    typedef EqualBy< S, int, &S::field1 > EqualByField1; // it works, but I do not want to derive :)
};
```

Thanx. And sorry for my ugly english :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is no ugly :-)
Though I'm not 100% confident that this really meets your aim, the following
work-around might help:

```
struct S {
    int field1;

    template< class T >
    struct TEqualByField1 {
        typedef EqualBy< T, int, &T::field1 > type;
    };
    typedef TEqualByField1< S >::type EqualByField1;
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes! It works even in MSVC 2008. Thank you.  It looks a little inconveniently, but works.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already correct. At least the parts you have shown. The compiler thinks that `&S::field1` is `&(S::field1)`. But what you wrote is not, as it correctly wants to have a member pointer.

This appears to be a compiler related problem.

Comment: > This appears to be a compiler related problem.  It seems to me that you are right, because I tried to compile it by Borland Builder and by gcc and there was no errors.

Comment: Yes. I hit the same problem in 2010 express. Offending code works fine with Clang/LLVM.